# Migrating GIS Stack

Tags: postgis, geoserver, software-recommendations, hosting, geomoose

I'm currently running the following GIS stack with a private hosting firm.

GeoServer v2.5.2
PostgreSQL v9.3.5 / PostGIS v2.1
GeoMoose v2.6

I would like to find a less expensive option for hosting.  I'm researching options like Amazon EC2, linode, and a2hosting.
I would like to learn how to do this for myself and  need some input from anyone who has experience with this.  Ideally I'd like to just migrate my current stack, db, and webmaps to another host.

I should add that I am an experienced desktop GIS guy and have understand the functionality of GeoServer and how GeoMoose uses mapbooks.  I just have questions about the server side of things and installing software.  My current host said he would be able to provide me with a server footprint If I wanted to host elsewhere.

The maps I'm building are state wide maps and contain between 25-35 layers.  So far I have 9 maps and will probably increase that to 15 in the next year.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  As it stands I think your question needs more focussing.  For example, I think "Is it possible to run a GIS stack [of] Geoserver v2.5.2 PostgreSQL v9.3.5 / PostGIS v2.1 GeoMoose v2.6 ... on a[n] Amazon EC2 ... server[?]" would be less likely to be closed as too broad than in its current open-ended form.  There is an [edit] button beneath it that you can use to keep refining it.

Comment: You can also check out the VPS offered by digitalocean (https://www.digitalocean.com/pricing/)

Answer (score 3):

Amazon's EC2 is really easy and fast to test and play with.

I don't know your background, but in my view, especially if you have some Linux background, it's pretty easy to get a Ubuntu + PostGIS + GeoServer + Nginx + Leaflet mapping system up. That gives you a lot of flexibility, but does require system administration and development. The cost can be something like $120/month for your EC2 server and backup.

The other alternative is using something like CartoDB or MapBox. That might save you money in hosting, and will definitely save you time, but will be less flexible.